# Plot legend upon checkbox activation in GUI

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide

I am new to matlab gui and working on my first program. I have ~10 datasets that I need to plot , but only when activated by a checkbox selection where two plots will be generated in axes1 and axes2. Sometimes I only want to activate some in random, but I need a lengend on those activateed. And I need the legend to disappear again upon unclicking the checkbox. I have made to plots behave as I want but I can't figure out how to handle the legend. The same legend (like Temperature) should appear in axes1  and axes2 when a checkbox is activated.
Here is my code so far:

```
function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  if get(handles.checkbox1,'Value')
    hold( handles.axes1, 'on' )
    handles.plotCDS1 = plot(dataS1(:,1),NormCdS1(:,1),'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes1);
    hold( handles.axes2, 'on' )
    handles.plotHTS1 = plot(dataS1(:,1),dataS1(:,3),'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes2);  
    guidata(hObject,handles);  % do this to save the updated handles structure
 else
     if ~isempty(handles.plotCDS1);
         delete(handles.plotCDS1); 
        ~isempty(handles.plotHTS1);  
         delete(handles.plotHTS1);
     end       
end
```

and the second checkbox:

```
  function checkbox2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  if get(handles.checkbox2,'Value')
    hold( handles.axes1, 'on' )
    handles.plotCDS2 = plot(dataS2(:,1),NormCdS2(:,1),'LineWidth',2,'Color', [1 0 0],'parent',handles.axes1);
    hold( handles.axes2, 'on' )
    handles.plotHTS2 = plot(dataS2(:,1),dataS2(:,3),'LineWidth',2,'Color', [1 0 0],'parent',handles.axes2);   
    guidata(hObject,handles);  % do this to save the updated handles structure
 else
     if ~isempty(handles.plotCDS2);
         delete(handles.plotCDS2); 
        ~isempty(handles.plotHTS2);  
         delete(handles.plotHTS2);
     end       
end
```

And then I have 8 checkboxes more. Please help... THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You need separate legends for each axis.  You can specify the axis within the `legend` calls.  Here's how it might look in your checkbox1 callback function:

```
...
if get(handles.checkbox1,'Value')
   % your plot code for axes 1  and 2
   ...

   legend(handles.axes1,'Location','northeast'); % modify according to desired labels and such.
   legend(handles.axes2,'Location','northeast');

 else
    % turn things off like before

    legend(handles.axes1,'off'); 
    legend(handles.axes2,'off'); 
 end
```

By the way, you may have a bug in your code.  The result from a successful `plot` call is the axis handle that was plotted to.  That is, `handles.plotCDS1` is the same value as `handles.axis1`.  Something to look into further is you are getting strange behavior.